# How to change the order of options in "run as" menu in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I mainly develop for Android in Eclipse. I used to run my app in with shortcut "CTRL+F11" which was the same as clicking "run as android application" in menu.
Then i installed some eclipse plugins for webservices and now when i press "CTRL+F11", it calls "run on server" because this is the first option in "run as" menu.

How can i change this so the default option for run as would be "run as android application"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `Preferences → Run/Debug → Launching` to `Always launch the previously launched application`, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> should launch what you last launched.

Simply relaunch your app manually, then check that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> works like you want.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> always launches your **last** launched configuration if the `Preferences → Run/Debug → Launching to Always launch the previously launched application` preference is set.

You can try to add a new shortcut for running android apps by customizing the key-shortcut preferences:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

"Organize Favorites" Just below the run as menu.